# grafico de densidad usando cdplot

Tags: r, rstudio

Pude realizar este grafico de densidad de tasa de incidencia por grupo de edad, sin embargo tengo 3 problemas:

1. No esta utilizando la variable año.
2. Se superponen los colores de los grupos de edad.
3. No hay un orden en los grupos de edad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega  el código y los datos que estas usando., así podemos reproducir  el problema y ayudarte